# String interpolation allocations

Tags: c#, .net-core, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I'm running some benchmarks to determine heap allocations for interpolated strings, especially around using value types inside of them. I have this as an example:

```
var str = $"Hello world {Guid.NewGuid()}";
```

This causes boxing due to interpolated string being syntactic sugar for `string.Format` and `string.Format` accepts an `object`. You can see the `IL` for this:

```
IL_0000: ldstr "Hello world {0}"
IL_0005: call valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Guid [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Guid::NewGuid()
IL_000a: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Guid
IL_000f: call string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String::Format(string, object)
IL_0014: ret
```

So the solution to avoid this boxing it to call `ToString()` on `Guid`, which is a `struct` and this method has been [overridden](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,a6547a472def7796,references)

```
var str = $"Hello world {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";
```

`IL` for this is

```
IL_0000: call valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Guid [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Guid::NewGuid()
IL_0005: stloc.1
IL_0006: ldloca.s 1
IL_0008: constrained. [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Guid
IL_000e: callvirt instance string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object::ToString()
IL_0013: stloc.0
IL_0014: ldstr "Hello world "
IL_0019: ldloc.0
IL_001a: call string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String::Concat(string, string)
IL_001f: ret
```

My first benchmarks were to confirm that calling `Guid.ToString()` does in fact allocate less than a boxed virtual call. i.e.

```
var str = Guid.ToString();
```

allocates less than

```
object o = Guid.NewGuid();
var str = o.ToString();
```

and this was indeed the case. So after this, I was expecting `$"Hello world {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}"` to allocate less. My assumption was very wrong. This method allocates 72 bytes more than the boxing one.

Why would this be the case? Below is the benchmark I used and the results

```
[Benchmark]
public static string NoBox()
{
    return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

[Benchmark]
public static string Box()
{
    object o = Guid.NewGuid();
    return o.ToString();
}

[Benchmark]
public static string WithToString()
{
    return $"Hello world {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";
}

[Benchmark]
public static string WithoutToString()
{
    return $"Hello world {Guid.NewGuid()}";
}


|          Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |  Gen 0 |  Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|---------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|-------:|------:|----------:|
|           NoBox | 215.9 ns | 5.362 ns | 15.47 ns | 0.0246 |      - |     - |     104 B |
|             Box | 224.8 ns | 4.563 ns | 11.78 ns | 0.0322 | 0.0002 |     - |     136 B |
|    WithToString | 238.7 ns | 4.856 ns | 11.91 ns | 0.0553 |      - |     - |     232 B |
| WithoutToString | 337.2 ns | 6.771 ns | 17.24 ns | 0.0381 |      - |     - |     160 B |
```

Comment: Don't forget,  Guid.ToString and string.Format have implementations too.

Comment: Seems to me that if you really want to compare apples-to-apples, you need to use `$"Hello world {((object)Guid.NewGuid()).ToString()}"` in your "boxing" scenario. Because the difference between `string.Format()` and `string.Concat()` could easily explain the observed difference. Also, did you bother to look at _what_ was being allocated? Just knowing the count of bytes that were allocated doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @madreflection I'm not sure I follow you. I was expecting calling `Guid.ToString()` to allocate less than having to box it, then calling `ToString()` on the object, which it was but when that is done inside an interpolated string, it isn't

Comment: hrm you are right, all we can say is hmm interesting. The answers to the why are probably nested in non trivial places and would be largely implementation details not to mention may change with future versions. Any answer now might not be valid in the future. So... you are on the right track, if you need to micro optimise this, then do what you are doing and find the best way for you now. There is not much more we can really add to this.. Said in the nicest possible way

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but I think that's because it allocates this first: Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), and then the string interpolation calls the string.Format(), which allocates the hole thing: Hello world {Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}. You can check that in the memory tab in Rider while debugging. So the first one which is toString() allocated 104 B, so the WithToString() would be: 104 B (first time) + 104 B (second time) + "Hello world \n".
May have missed something but that's the idea